# Difference between Rsrc-Class-Path and Class-Path

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest.mf

can someone tell me please what are the difference between `Rsrc-class-Path` and `Class-Path` sections of a runnable-jar's mannifest file?

Now I take them as granted as generated by Eclipse, but I'd like to understand how it works.

What I think based on how Eclipse generates code seems that the first is about jars my app needs, the second is always `.`. But I have no clues what folder `.` refers to.

Comment: `.` is always the current folder, while `..` is the parent folder.

Comment: Sure it is, anyway my question's about what `class-path` current folder and `Rsrc-class-path` current folder?

Answer (score 1):

The `Class-Path` attribute.  This is a standard attribute defined by the [JAR file specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#class-path-attribute).  It contains a list of relative URLs for that will be included on the runtime classpath when you run the JAR using `java -jar ...`.

This provides a way to add external JARs (and directories) to the runtime classpath.  The entries must be relative, and are resolved relative to the directory containing the main JAR.  (For security reasons ...)

The `Rsrc-class-Path` attribute is non-standard.  This is used by Eclipse's "jars-in-jar" launcher.  A typical manifest looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Main-Class: com.abc.Master
Main-Class: com.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ lib/xyz.jar
```

where `com.abc.Master` is your apps (real) main class, and `lib/xyz.jar` is a relative URL for a JAR file that is *nested within this JAR.*.  You will also see that the JAR contains the ".class" file for `JarRsrcLoader`.
This is what happens with you run `java -jar this.JAR arg1 arg2`.

1. The JVM is created
2. The JVM jar loader opens the JAR, reads and parses the MANIFEST.MF above.
3. It loads the `JarRsrcLoader` class given by `Main-Class`/
4. It calls the above classes `main` method, passing it `["arg1", "arg2"]`
5. The `JarRsrcLoader` examines the manifest, and extracts the `Rsrc-Class-Path` and `Rsrc-Main-Class`.
6. Then `JarRsrcLoader` creates a special classloader that knows how read JARs embedded within the current JAR.  The classpath for this classloader is "./" follows by "lib/xyz.jar", where these URLs are resolved *within* the outer JAR file.
7. Then `JarRsrcLoader` loads the class `com.abc.Master` using the special class loader.
8. Then `JarRsrcLoader` calls the `main` method for `com.abc.Master`, passing the same string array containing the arguments.
9. Finally, the application runs.

In short, `Rsrc-Class-Path` is an attribute that the `JarRsrcLoader` class understands, and uses to construct the actual application classpath.

In this context, the `Class-Path: .` attribute serves no real purpose.  Everything needed to run `JarRsrcLoader` will be in the JAR.

---

As a final note, the SpringBoot loading mechanism is similar, but it uses a different non-standard attribute for the application's main class, and puts the application's resources (e.g. JARs) into a particular directory ("/boot-inf") within the main JAR.